# find which link caused route to change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

The application uses angularjs. I have a navigation bar which opens pages and also another UI which also opens the same pages(same links).

I am using `$locationChangeStart` to toggle open the sub-menu in the navbar when I open a page from the other UI.

When I open the same page from the from the navigation bar, the toggle happens and the sub-menu of navbar closes.

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 

  $rootScope.hashUrl = next.split('#').pop();
  $rootScope.hashUrl = '#' + $rootScope.hashUrl;
  console.log($rootScope.hashUrl, "URL");   //#!/addflats
  $rootScope.addActiveToSidebarElement(event, next, current);

});
```

The function the `locationChangeStart` calls:

```
$rootScope.addActiveToSidebarElement = function(event, next, current) {
  $rootScope.anchorElement = $("a[href='" + $rootScope.hashUrl + "']");
  if (parentLi.hasClass('associationChildLi')) {
    $rootScope.anchorElement.addClass('selectedSideBarChildActive');
    $('.associationUl').slideToggle();
  }
}
```

Both links(from navigation bar and other UI) cause the route change. How do I find which link caused the route to change?

**Edit**:

I will try to explain better. I have two links that open the same page. One link from a navigation bar, one from a tile.

When I open the page, I want to highlight the respective nav item. It works naturally when I use  the navigation bar. When I open the page from the tile, I have to highlight the nav item.

So I am using `$locationChangeStart` to detect which route I am currently on and find the `<li><a href='#!/addflats'>link</a></li>` element in the navigation bar
which matches the current route and add a class that highlights it.

I need to find which link(navigation bar or tile) caused the route to change

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more?

Comment: Assuming `event` is the pre-defined AngularJS object, you can see what `event.target` is with `console.log(event.target)`. It will output the HTML of the clicked on element.

Comment: @JM-AGMS hey, just saw your comment. I don't see a `event.target`. I only see `event.targetScope`

Comment: Could you just add a simple query-string parameter to the URl to identify the source? What should happen if the user navigates to the URL *directly*, by typing it into the URL or bookmarking the page, for example?

Comment: I think the locationChangeStart deals with currentScope and targetScope rather than target element. Would it be possible for you to use ng-click as well on the links, that way you can use event.target ... I tried something similar http://plnkr.co/edit/jdrjeQvd9eRjLqNyGbK7 
Just a heads up.. I used someone else's plunker.. and edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two links that you want to differentiate you could add a search term to the URL:

```
<li><a href='#!/addflats?from=nav'>link</a></li>
```

and

```
<li><a href='#!/addflats?from=tile'>link</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Just to clarify, it sounds like your goal is different from your question. I will attempt to address what sounds like your goal: 'Highlight a nav item that reflects my active state'.*

I would think that you would want to use [$locationChangeSuccess](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#event-$locationChangeSuccess) because using start will likely put you before whatever DOM manipulations happen during and after the state change which could include a reload of your navigation template.

It is important to note, you should not be making these DOM manipulations in a controller. At the very least, you should have a controller around your navigation and have $scope variables that you can bind to these navigation items with ng-class.

> Once you are using a controller around your nav, you can listen to the
>   $locationChangeSuccess event from that controller, inspect the new url that
>   is returned and set the appropriate $scope variable(s).

---

If you are using ui-router this becomes a great deal easier because you can simply use `ng-class="{'active':$state.includes('example.state')}"` on the nav html element in question [AngularUI: $state.includes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateincludesstatename--params)

Comment: i cant use `ng-class` because the nav items are dynamically generated. so adding ng-class to it wont work. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It's very handy to add references to $state and $stateParams to the $rootScope
so that you can access them from any scope within your applications.

You can try `ui-sref-active` directive in module `ui.router.state` , that alongside `ui-sref` to add classes to an element when the related ui-sref directive's state is active, and removing them when it is inactive. `ui-sref-active` can live on the same element as ui-sref or on a parent element. The first ui-sref-active found at the same level or above the ui-sref will be used. Will activate when the ui-sref's target state or any child state is active.

here is working plunker http://next.plnkr.co/plunk/dY3NluIyEFU7yuhh , when you click on `Route 1` it will show you `route1.html` and its state will change to active, and same when you `click Route 2` if you click on `R1 items` inside route1.html it will navigate to route2,HTML and will change state of `Route 2` to active.

Hope that's what you looking.

Comment: i think your answer assumes i am using ui-router.? i am not using it

Comment: You right, That's why I Updated the tag too. My bad

Answer (score -1):

Bubbling principle of DOM might help you in this scenario.
When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors.

Similarly here click event occurs on  tag it handles that event and move all the way up to its parent tag.
So when you will click on the ui buttons it will give you parent tag as  and when you will click on navbar buttons it will give you  as parent tag and you will get to know which route has been hit.

see this example

```js
document.getElementById("ui").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
document.getElementById("navbar").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
 alert("Parent Tag Name-"+this.tagName)
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="ui">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">News</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
</div>
<br>
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a >Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
```